# Why does multiple calls to xalloc result in delayed output?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

When I print the id of a stream in a single expression it prints it backwards. Normally this is what comes out:

```
std::stringstream ss;

std::cout << ss.xalloc() << '\n';
std::cout << ss.xalloc() << '\n';
std::cout << ss.xalloc();
```

Output is:

> 4
>   5
>   6

But when I do it in one expression it prints backwards, why?

```
std::stringstream ss;

std::cout << ss.xalloc() << '\n'
          << ss.xalloc() << '\n'
          << ss.xalloc();
```

Output:

> 6
>   5
>   4

I know the order of evaluation is unspecified but then why does the following always result in the correct order:

```
std::cout << 4 << 5 << 6;
```

Can someone explain why `xalloc` behaves differently? Thanks.

Comment: You can't observe the order in which `4`, `5`, and `6` are evaluated - only the order in which they are passed to `cout`. You *can* observe the order in which the three `ss.xalloc()` expressions are evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to `xalloc`; any other function that returns a different value each time it's called would do the same thing. The order of **evaluation** of the arguments is unspecified; the compiler can make the three function calls in any order. Once all the arguments have been evaluated, the order of **insertion** is from left to right.